# How can I get only specific values from an Arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist

I have an `ArrayList<Integer>` with values `(20, 40, 60, 80, 100, 120)` Is it possible to only retrieve the position `2-5` only which is `60, 80, 100 and 120`? Thanks for any help.

```
for (DataSnapshot price : priceSnapshot.getChildren()) {
    int pr = price.getValue(Integer.class);
    priceList.add(pr); // size is 61 
}
int total = 0;
List<Integer> totalList = 
            new ArrayList<Integer>(priceList.subList(29, 34));               
for (int i = 0; i < totalList.size(); i++) {
    int to = totalList.get(i);
    total += to;
    txtPrice.setText(String.valueOf(total));
}
```

Comment: Kotlin or Java ?

Comment: @MehrdadPedramfar java sir! please help :(

Comment: I think below answer works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Java you can create a sublist ([javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList-int-int-)) of a list; e.g.

```
List<Integer> list = ...
List<Integer> sublist = list.sublist(2, 6);
```

Notes:

1. The the upper bound is exclusive, so that to get the list element containing `120` we must specify `6` as the upper bound, not `5`.
2. The resulting sublist is "backed" by the original list.  Therefore:

   - there is no copying involved in creating the sublist, and
   - changes to the sublist will modify the corresponding positions in the original list.

Comment: Hi stephen the parameters of `sublist are fromIndex and toIndex` will the `2 became 0 index and 6 into 4?` I'm a bit confused or still oni the same position?

Comment: The sublist elements are numbered from zero, as you observed.  Element 2 of the old list is element 0 of the sublist, etcetera.  It is done this way to conform to the `List` API ... which *specifies* that the first element of a `List` is at position 0.

Comment: Hey stephen I have an arraylist that has a `size of 61` I only want to get index 29-34 I'm having an error `IndexOutOfBoundsException` I don't get why? but if I use `subList(29, list.size())` No error please help

Comment: You need to explain clearly 1) how you are calling `sublist` and 2) where / how you are getting the exception.  (My guess is that you didn't comprehend my note 1.

Comment: I'm still confused I don't get it. I edited my post can you check? Why is it not working

Comment: I tried also `subList(29,5)` still error since it can be `fromIndex > toIndex`

Comment: Where is the exception occuring?  What is the complete exception stacktrace?  How do you know that `size` is really `61` when you call `sublist`?  Are elements being added or removed from either list in a separate thread?  *Might* that be happening?

Comment: I set the `priceList.size() into TextView` that's why I know the size of the priceList. exception is occuring in `List<Integer> totalList = 
            new ArrayList<Integer>(priceList.subList(29, 34)); `

Comment: I'll explain what i want to do. So I have `two dates` which is the check-in and check-out. I'm using firebase as my database since I can't use the query from firebase if it's different month and for my data structure also this is my alternative way to get the total price. I get all the days of `check-in and check-out` then add it to the `priceList` i'll get the total between check-in and check-out.I don't know why I'm having an error if my check-in for example is March 30 in array `0 based index is 29` then check-out is `April 4 is 34`

Comment: If your code *really* as shown in your question, and `priceList.size()` is *really* 61 and there are *really* no other threads (or code) changing things, then what you say is happening *should not happen*.  You need to provide an MCVE that we can run to see what is happening.

Comment: So I tried `List<Integer> totalList = new ArrayList<Integer>(priceList.subList(29, priceList.size()));` this the size is `33` if I set `TextView.setText(totalList.size());` and if I check it in debug mode it's only `3` lol

Comment: Yea.  There's a lesson in this.  If you are getting weird outputs / exceptions, don't *assume* that the inputs are what you think they are.  Check it.  (I assume that your LOL means you have figured out your mistake ... or at least, why you are getting an exception from the `sublist` call.)

Comment: I'm still a beginner need to learn more but I still don't get this `subList`. Check my code any tips on how to get the position 29-34

Comment: I'm pretty sure I'm doing it correctly followed all the guides. Why I still can't get it :(

Comment: `priceList.subList(29, 34)`  gives you the sublist of the original list contain the elements at positions 29, 30, 31, 32 and 33.  Is that what you want?   I assume that you know what "inclusive" and "exclusive" mean ...

Comment: Yup that is what I want but if i set it to 34 there's an error.

Comment: I got it now. There's no error with the code. What is wrong i placed it in a wrong spot. Should put `List<Integer> totalList = new ArrayList<Integer>(priceList.subList(29, 34)); ` outside the loop

Comment: A real MCVE would have established that much sooner.  According to the code you showed us, the `sublist` call **is** outside the loop.